# what is Difference between RedirectToAction() and View()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, view

I am beginner in asp.net MVC

I have a Person Class like this

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
}
```

and i have a ActionResult Create Like below

```
 public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        db.Person.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //retrun View (Index);
    }
```

When i use RedirectToAction, The My Project Run without any Error, but When i use Return View I face With Error. what is difference between these ??

Note: the Index View Show all information in Person table

Comment: so you don't care what's inside the Index Action, imagine that you will change the View inside the Index action to `Dashboard`... now you will need to change everywhere... by redirecting to an Action, you're not coupled with a view...

Answer (score 0):

In your Create method, it should be a POST Method. A better design pattern to use redirect by
Post-Redirect-Get pattern.

Please take a glance at this introduction [Wikipedia : Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)